# Qt and openCV program doesn't even start with release lib

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a Qt projet using openGL and openCV.
But when I use the release dll of openCV, the program instantly crash, I can't even launch it with the debugger, it fails saying "The CDB process terminated" and I don't have any debugger log.

Including the debug dll in the .pro fix this. However, the openCV findContour function has a know crash when mixing release and debug, and it's not good to got debug libs in a release build anyway.

I must precise that this bugs not only happens on a single computer but on my colleague's computer too, so I don't think the installation is broken.

(config is Windows 7 / Qt 5.2.1 / msvc2012 64 bit openGL / openCV 2.4.13)

Anyone had similar problem or have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known QTcreator bug. Please check
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15456

Comment: Bug is told to be fixed in Qt Creator 3.6.0, I got 3.6.1, so is that really the same bug?

Comment: Yes, people are still reporting the same buh. Sorry to tell you.

Comment: @Krapow You can try to uncheck "Enable QML debugging and profiling", and let me know if you still get the error

Comment: OK but this concern the fact CDB doesn't show anything, but I still get and openCV bug.

Comment: I'm afraid that, as far as my knowledge goes, this is not a bug in your code, but rather in the dependencies

Comment: "Enable QML debugging and profiling" was unchecked.

Comment: No, I mean, it was already unchecked.
It is weird to me that there is dependency bug as debug and release libs are in the same directory and debug libs are found.

Comment: Then i'm afraid i cant help any further, i'm sorry. This is indeed weird, and almost impossible. Consider filing a bug report at www.bugreports.qt.io, the website i originally posted as an answer.